# Webservice, Android-Client, SSL

Tags: android, web-services, ssl

I'm writing a web-service (Rest) and an Android app, using that service.
There is no login, no session - instead login-data (username, password) is sent on EVERY call to that service (via **org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost** on an **org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient**).
In order to secure the communication, I will "install" a simple SSL-Certificate (128 bit) on my web-server and make calls via "https".
Is this the right way to do this?
Will the communication (sending password via POST) be secured this way?

The server will store some kinda hash for the passwords (md5, sha1)...should Android send the password and let the webservice generate the hash or should it send the hash?

On Android, do I store the password or the hash (private preference)?

Answer (score 0):

This is a big question. Bigger than what can be easily addressed within the scope of a short answer. I think it's a good thing though that you are asking these questions, because that shows you're aware of the risks involved.

I can try to give you some pointers, at least. First of all, md5 and sha1 are not adequate algorithms for securing user credentials, and the process of hashing and salting the hashes is a chapter in its own right. Check out [Secure Salted Password Hashing - Doing it Right](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) and maybe [Our password hashing has no clothes](http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/06/our-password-hashing-has-no-clothes.html) for some background. And check out bcrypt or PBKDF2 as better suited hashing algorithms.

When it comes to the architecture in general, I'd suggest thinking along the lines of authenticating the user in one call to get some sort of authentication token, and then use this token for subsequent communications, rather than sending the credentials i every call. This not only would improve security, but also performance, especially if using deliberately time consuming cryptographic hashing algorithms (like bcrypt or PBKDF2). Also, remember that the token should be tied to the user identity, and not just some "authenticated session". This is something that you should probably not implement yourself, but rather rely on some mechanism in the framework you're using. Session management is tricky, e.g. [Ramping up ASP.NET Session Security](http://www.dotnetnoob.com/2013/07/ramping-up-aspnet-session-security.html) (<- not ASP.NET specific).

In any case, the hashing should be performed where you store the hashes. That is, authentication, hashing and storing should all be the responsibility of the service, not the client. Beware of any kind of implementation vulnerable to [replay attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack).

SSL is all good and that (an absolute must, even), but if it were me, I'd consider securing not only the transport layer, but also that the caller is authorized to use the service, i.e. using certificates. I'm am not familiar with the inner workings of the Android platform, so I cant advice on how to do this securely in that context.

Finally (I have a meeting to attend ;), if you ever think this all may be "overkill", just remember that [60 percent of users use the same password](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/security/survey-60-percent-of-users-use-the-same-password-across-more-than-one-of-their-online-accounts/9489), and that it is our responsibility as developers to take good care of the trust they invest in our skills.

Good luck, and keep up your quest for a secure solution!

Comment: Many thanks, Oskar!
That's a lot to consider (in deed I knew, it's not a simple question :o)...so I will read this (and the links provided) and will let you know about MY solution...
Have fun at your meeting!
Will

Comment: Great answers, eventhough the question was broad. Thank you for taking the time to give useful leads.